# Get player_id from OneSignal on page load

Tags: javascript, push-notification, onesignal

I am implementing web push notifications using [Onesigal](https://onesignal.com/) API.

```
    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "07aae1f0-xxxx-xxxx-aa7a-21c79c5b6733",
        'include_player_ids'=>['57dd3f80-xxxx-xxxx-adb0-294bfa69621a'],
        'contents' => array( "en"=> "message" )
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                               'Authorization: Basic YTdmYTYxYzYtN...tNjVlNzJkNDFlZmMz'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem' );
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Above code sends a push notification to the user if you know his `player_id`. But suppose if some user visits my site and subscribes to push notifications and leaves.Later again he visits (he is already subscribed) and favs.(adds to favorite) a currently out of stock product.**So how can I get `player_id`** of this user which I can store in `"subs_fav"` table ?

```
id  player_id           product_id
1   57dd3f80...a69621a  p097
```

When that product becomes available `pushFav()` function will run which would notify the user that the product is now available and they can buy it but for that we should know the player_id of the user who favd. this product. I want to know how to find this player_id so that I can send it `addToFav()` ajax call to store in `"sub_fav"` table

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it! all you need is `OneSignal.getUserId()` passed in a callback, which gives the user's `player_id` upon querying. Before calling make sure user has actually subscribed.

```
OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled(function(isEnabled) {
  if (isEnabled) {
      // user has subscribed
      OneSignal.getUserId( function(userId) {
          console.log('player_id of the subscribed user is : ' + userId);
          // Make a POST call to your server with the user ID        
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you use node library or how are you importing one signal?

Comment: I used simple `<script src>` tag to import one signal lib but you can also node based imports

Comment: Oh.. Thank you. But I could not find documentation, how to import as npm. Currently, I'm trying to integrate with react project, Can you look into the issue I raised at https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/issues/410

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via Javascript:  Just add this to your header.php or footer.php.
Create your path in the controller to save it via database, etc.

```
<script>
  var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
  OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.init({
      appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      autoRegister: false,
      notifyButton: {
        enable: true,
      },
    });
    OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications();
  });
     OneSignal.push(function() {
      OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {

        var user_id = <?php echo (Sentry::getUser()->id) ?? 0; ?>;
        var token   = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

        $.post("/user/storeUserPath", {
            'user_id': user_id,
            '_token': token,
            'userId': userId,
        });

      });
    });
</script>
```